# Authenticate to google cloud function from local dev environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions

My Flask application authenticates once deployed but I'd like to run it locally for testing obviously, however it needs to authenticate with google. I'm using the the below to do that authentication when its deployed, but how can I create a JWT token locally?

```
def invoke_cloud_function(function_url, payload):
    # Make sure to replace variables with appropriate values
    receiving_function_url = function_url

    # Set up metadata server request
    metadata_server_token_url = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience='

    token_request_url = metadata_server_token_url + receiving_function_url
    token_request_headers = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}

    # Fetch the token
    token_response = requests.get(token_request_url, headers=token_request_headers)
    jwt = token_response.content.decode("utf-8")

    # Provide the token in the request to the receiving function
    receiving_function_headers = {'Authorization': f'bearer {jwt}'}
    function_response = requests.get(receiving_function_url, params=payload, headers=receiving_function_headers)

    return function_response.json()
```

It's trying to point to `metadata_server_token_url = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=` which will only be local to the deployed app engine.

I need a one size fits all way of authenticating to the cloud function. I do have an environ var set to a service account key, but that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation [Accessing Instance Metadata](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/accessing-instance-metadata).

> The metadata server is available for deployed applications: running
>   locally on the development server is not supported. You can add an
>   environment check to your code to expect metadata results only if the
>   app is running in production.

```
 env =  os.environ.get('PROD', 'Specified environment variable is not set.')

 // The metadata server is only on a production system
 if env == "Production":
     //show metadata results
```